# Resolving IE8/9 SCRIPT16387 Invalid pointer Javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate

I have a JSMin-compressed Javascript file, composed mostly of jQuery libraries, and it causes IE9 and IE8 to throw the error `SCRIPT16387: Invalid pointer`. The line number given by IE corresponds to a couple custom jQuery validation methods:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("emaillist", function(value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || /^(\s*,?\s*[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\s*,?\s*){1,}$/im.test(value);
}, "Please specify at least one email address. Separate multiple addresses with a comma.");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("decimal", function(value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?\.?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/im.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid number.");
```

Googling shows all of [10 results](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=IE%20SCRIPT16387%20Invalid%20pointer) for this error, and no solutions. Naturally, everything works find in Firefox/Chrome/Safari/etc. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: When is the error actually thrown, when the validator methd is called? Does it happen with unminified jQuery files, and if yes in which line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the error by wrapping the above functions in jQuery's:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```